# How do I display sql statement?

Tags: sql, xml, vb.net

I have function which is using `id_judge` from xml document and then I would like to use that id_judge to create a sql *select* statement. This statement will be a string in `strOutputSql` variable.

Every sql *select* statement will be the same. The only difference will be `CodeID` because this is the variable for the `id_judge`.

Right now my Function's `Return strOutputSql` is showing only "09002P" . I would like to modify this variable to instead show the sql statement which I have pasted below under header Expected sql output.

How do I do this inside my function?

For the xml document I have, my Function should return the following output inside the string variable `strOutputSql`

Expected sql output

```sql
select * 
from ucode as uc
inner join uJudOffc as uj on (uj.JudicialOffCodeID = uc.CodeID)
where Code='09002P'
and uc.CacheTableID = 136
FOR XML PATH('JudgeCode')
```

My vb.net 4.0 code

```vb
Private Class MessageProcessor
    Inherits Msc.Integration.MessageBroker.Library.v4.XmlMessageProcessor

    Protected Overrides Sub ProcessMessage(ByRef aobjBroker As MessageBroker.Library.v4.Broker, ByRef aobjXmlInputDoc As System.Xml.XmlDocument, ByRef aobjInstantiatedObjectsCollection As Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection)
    MyBase.ProcessMessage(aobjBroker, aobjXmlInputDoc, aobjInstantiatedObjectsCollection)
    Dim objXmlLoadedElement As XmlElement
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim strJudgeId As String

    objXmlLoadedElement = aobjXmlInputDoc.CreateElement("Loaded")
    aobjXmlInputDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(objXmlLoadedElement)

    strJudgeId = aobjXmlInputDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("id_judge").InnerText
    strSql = GetSql(strJudgeId)
    End Sub

    Function GetSql(ByVal astrJudgeId As String) As String
    Dim strOutputSql As String

    strOutputSql = astrJudgeId

    Return strOutputSql
    End Function
End Class
```

My xml document with `id_judge` "09002P" that is used to create the sql statement in vb.net function.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GJUDGE triggerEvent="Update" xmlns="">
   <id_judge>09002P</id_judge>
    <Loaded>
        <JudgeCode>
            <CodeID>7598</CodeID>
            <CacheTableID>136</CacheTableID>
            <RevisionID>5321</RevisionID>
            <Code>07001G</Code>
            <RootNodeID>0</RootNodeID>
            <EffectiveDate>2007-06-14T00:00:00</EffectiveDate>
            <UserIDCreate>1</UserIDCreate>
            <TimestampCreate>2003-02-01T16:45:00</TimestampCreate>
            <UserIDChange>1</UserIDChange>
            <TimestampChange>2015-07-06T09:49:27.700</TimestampChange>
            <Description>Amos,Wako ,</Description>
            <JudicialOffCodeID>7598</JudicialOffCodeID>
            <NameFirst>Amos</NameFirst>
            <NameLast>Wako</NameLast>
            <UnavailableOnly>1</UnavailableOnly>
            <Private>0</Private>
        </JudgeCode>
    </Loaded>
</GJUDGE>
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something here, but:    `strOutputSQL = "select * from ucode as uc inner join uJudOffc as uj on (uj.JudicialOffCodeID = uc.CodeID) where Code='" & astrJudgeId & "' and uc.CacheTableID = 136 FOR XML PATH('JudgeCode')"`

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful using basic string concatenation when assembling SQL statements, particularly when you don't control the source.  This is unsafe and opens you up for potential SQL injections.

The more appropriate way to do this is to use `Parameters` with a `Command` object.  See this Microsoft article for an example.  It is for an SQL `UPDATE` but the principle still works for `SELECT`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: Joehanna thanks for your advice and I also agree with your premise. I will talk to my boss and see what needs to be changed. I will read the article for sure.